# How do I make shadows through glass and liquid more transparent and less opaque?

Tags: light, shadows, glass

Andrew's glass:[image: Andrew's glass]

My glass:[image: my glass]

Light paths settings:[image: setting] None of these seem to change the shadow (or rather the cup's?) see through

What settings can I possibly fiddle with? the more the merrier! :)

Comment: Hi Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Sorry thank you I will do that in the future

Comment: Hi, is it possible that you could please share the file along with the blender version.

Comment: 2.92.0 here is the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/8bca9371217c418a84115dc3dc9c5d32

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219957/110840

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little progress, turning off Filter Glossy to 0 under Caustics seem to have worked. I played around with the other Light Paths after and this is what I got so far: [image: light] and lamp setting: [image: lamp]

I will continue the tutorial now, maybe he will mention his Light paths settings at some point.