# Donut glass cup render has too many grains and speckles + denoiser come out distorted, shadow is also too opaque. What settings may I try out?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, shadows, denoise, noise-reduction

I feel I am nearing completion of the tutorial but am still having gaps in knowledge on how to render light properly.

2.92.0 **blender file: https://pasteall.org/blend/6474d6f8bd5f4b1abbabaa41478e7e6a**

Overview layout: [image: https://i.imgur.com/uFHAQSa.png]

Lamp:

[image: lamp]

128 sample before denoise: [image]

128 sample after denoise: [image]

1024 sample 1080p 100% render before denoise: [image]

1024 sample 1080p 100% render after denoise: [image]

I've been trying different Light paths, but I honestly don't understand the extent of how they interact with each other. I haven't seen any example of what those numbers should be in the tutorial either, if someone knows please let me know. [Previously turning off 'Filter Glossy' under caustics improved the shadow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219037/how-do-i-make-shadows-through-glass-and-liquid-more-transparent-and-less-opaque/219122#219122) but it is now again a little bit too opaque, dunno when that happened. :D

Not too sure what I am missing out so any suggestions would be lovely! Thank you in advance

Comment: I ended up making a new project and appending the cup, donut, sprinkles in their respective collections into the new blender project *and lighting appears ok now!* :D Never found out what went wrong in my old file, there is some setting hidden in there that made shadows iffy.

Answer (score 0):

I just loaded your file and did this: checked both denoising checkmarks

[image]

viewport result:

[image]

render result:

[image]

is this ok for you?

Comment: [Denoise in sampling](https://i.imgur.com/Um4aawK.png) and [Denoise node](https://i.imgur.com/XSQ7AL0.png) ,

And [ticked in layer properties](https://i.imgur.com/myo7guJ.png)

I've tried unticking one or the other but it does not improve my output.

Can you please share your light paths settings that you used on yours or were they included in my blend file too? Some threads are mentioning Direct light and Indirect light in older blender versions but that is not seeming to help either

Comment: As I wrote, I just loaded your blend file and checked the two checkmarks - I did not more. Then I just rendered it out and made some screenshots.

Comment: Alright, I tried  doing what you did but it is not coming out as your render. If anything comparing the Composite layers in the render there seem to be some double distortion going on. There is also this Denoising menu that appears under Layer properties, do I leave these settings as they are? https://i.imgur.com/CzrBaXP.png

Comment: what blender version do you use?

Comment: Blender version 2.92.0, on my GPU Radeon RX 5700 if that matters

Comment: maybe load your blender file from your link again (maybe you have changed something in between) and just check the 2 checkboxes -> then render it out.

Comment: I just tried this by turning on Denoise NLM and it is still distorted: https://i.imgur.com/SVUDkxe.png 

I also tried turning off/on the Denoising menu that appears under Layer properties when you enable the denoiser in Render properties. If that one is ticked on there will be denoising applied DURING the render, as well as an additional Denoising AFTER the render so two denoising total. If I turn off this Denoise menu in Layer properties there will only be one denoising applied after the render - but it still comes out distorted.

Comment: Update I was advised to turn off Denoise everywhere but in the Compositing, so I turned off Render Prop>Sampling>Denoising unticked, compositing still on, render result: https://i.imgur.com/Ga5YUdR.png

This automatically disables the Denoising menu in layer properties so it is turned off for sure. (I even made sure to untick this menu before disabling Denoise in sampling, no dice)

Denoising data under Layer prop>Passes is ticked, because it is related to the compositor, correct? https://i.imgur.com/dmkYrmW.png It disables the nodes if I untick it: https://i.imgur.com/RRnR14b.png