# Denoised render's shadows too distorted without Indirect light clamping - too opaque with Indirect clamping. How do these interact?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, compositing-nodes, denoise, caustics

You can read in my [previous thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219153/donut-glass-cup-render-has-too-many-grains-and-speckles-denoiser-come-out-dist) about my struggle with this part. I made a milestone just now, increasing Indirect clamp will remove the fireflies, however the shadows are now too opaque.

Render with Indirect Clamp to 0, lots of fireflies and denoise distort:[image]

same settings except I changed Image to Denoiser instead of Noisy image to Denoiser node, still distorted but more detail seem intact: [image]

Render with Indirect clamp set to 2.0, shadow too opaque: [image]

Render with Indirect clamp set to 5.0, this is the best result I got so far but I still feel is nowhere near the ideal result: [image]

This is Andrew's cup in the tutorial, the lighting I am aiming for:[image]

Am I focusing too much on Indirect clamp? Are there other settings I should attempt to play around with?

**I am using Blender 2.92.0 with my GPU Radeon RX 5700 here is my blender file: https://pasteall.org/blend/85a361fe32cd41378a4fe8721f693aa0**

If you attempt to render my file please let me know if any settings are local that I need to change, or if they are per blender file.

Comment: Andrew should enhanced his tut ...

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was closed, address raised the issues by editing it, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a new Blender project and appending the cup, donut, sprinkles in their respective collections into the new blender project *and lighting appears ok now!* :D Never found out what went wrong in my old file, there is some setting hidden in there that made shadows iffy.