# Square artifacts when shining light through material

Tags: materials, light, transparency

I am shining a light through a principled bsdf with transmission and getting weird square artifacts. Any ideas as to the cause?[image]

blend file: https://filebin.net/yhpnzpuic4lvree1/

Comment: These are denoising artifacts - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98510/how-to-properly-denoise-renderings?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: You are running into one of the challenges of rendering glass in blender.  The default settings make it so that glass casts a shadow and the light is *slowly* reconstituted by way of refractive and reflective caustics.  If you hide the glass bulb in your scene I'm sure you'll see that the light from your filament should be much brighter than what is shown with the glass active.

Comment: I have a more exhaustive answer on glass here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219303/glass-casting-shadows-and-not-looking-real/219957#219957