# Why does my transparent/glass material change the colours of objects that sit inside of it, how to fix this?

Tags: materials, node-editor, lighting, glass

How come my coloured material appears different when situated inside my glass/transparent material. is there a work around so that the colour displays correctly inside the glass?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, the color doesn't seem to have changed that much in terms of hue - it's only darker. Maybe it will help if you set the _Refraction BSDF_ and _Glossy BSDF_ to pure white instead of light grey. And is there a reason why you have to setup the glass material like this?

Answer (score 0):

The old standby cheat for the cycles glass shader may give you the results you want.

[image]

I have an answer on some glass interactions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219957/110840).