# Reduce noise in refractive caustics

Tags: glass, noise-reduction, caustics

I'm trying to smooth these puppies out.

I don't need realism, just no noise. The material which light is passing through is a *Principle BSDF*. Using Cycles X with no reflective or refractive caustics on.

[image: Render]
[image: Settings]

I tried the following:

- Checked the refractive caustics settings.
- Increase alpha of material.
- Modified IOR of material.
- Changed to Eevee (not desired).

Comment: Not really sure what kind of answer you expect to be honest. If noise is a problem, increase amount of samples a couple of times and/or use denoising.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230452/110840 you can use principled instead of glass bsdf here