# Need help with glass material

Tags: materials, procedural, glass

I was making a pinart in blender which is covered by glass or plastic. I used an hdri to light the scene.

But the problem is that the glass is reflecting the lights of the hdri and also giving a black tint to the board

**With Glass:**
[image]

**Without Glass:[image]**

My question is how do I get rid of the reflecting hdri? Also is the black tint due to noise in the glass? Is there a way to fix these problems. I guess a light path node would help but I was not able to fix it.

Thanks in advance

Blend File: https://pasteall.org/blend/5eb94d471c224fe4885340e81a051b37

Comment: would this video help? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnHaRq2OybI

Comment: I already tried this. This didn't work as on the edges of the glass you can clearly see that white color

Comment: Hello Maulik, maybe this helps - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219957/110840

Comment: Yes this fixed the black tint problem but how do I get rid of light reflection from the hdri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *Principled* or *Glass BSDF*, you might try *Refraction BSDF*.

Here is a mix that gives you a very slight amount of light source reflection.  You have to go very close to 1 to get any meaningful reduction.

[image]

The full solution probably looks like this:

[image]