# Plastic objects looks very dark inside a glass container

Tags: materials

I want to create a glass soap dispenser. A frosted glass look. The plastic tube in the soap container looks very dark. Please let me know how I can make it so that it looks like a regular, semi-transparent plastic tube. Also, is there a way to lessen the effect of the dark shading on this dispenser? What is making this dark shading?

[image]

This is the material for the dispenser.

[image]

This is the material for the plastic tube inside the dispenser.
[image]

Comment: Search this post for 'total internal reflection' and follow the youtube link.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219303/glass-casting-shadows-and-not-looking-real/219957#219957

Comment: Your Refraction BSDF IOR is also set to a non-realistic value, and in fact may not be doing much at all at a value of 1.

Comment: it seems super complicated to me, have you tried with a Principled BSDF only, or mix between BSDF and Glossy with a Layer Weight as factor, etc?

Comment: @moonboots I've tried the Principled BDSF but it doesn't look like thick glass, which is the look I'm going for.

Comment: @AllenSimpson I will take a look. Thanks.