# Cycles refraction on a plane glass is not physically correct?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, physics

I was trying to see how glass refracts light. I set up a scene with a conical light source facing a wall with a pane of glass in-between.

[image: Direct conical light on a wall]

Theoretically, the glass plane should refract to show an illumination on the screen (wall) with a lesser area. The schematic of the same is shown below.
[image]
However, Blender goes the other way and increases the area illuminated on the screen. This is not a physically accurate render for refraction. Am I doing anything wrong?

[image: Refraction of the same conical light with a flat glass pane. Cycles renderer is spreading out the light. This is not how a flat pane of glass refracts light.]

I have set up the node for the glass pane material as follows:
[image: Material setup]

Comment: Transmission 80??

Comment: Well, I just assumed glass would transmit about 80% of the light. However, even at 95% transmission, the result is qualitatively the same.

Comment: It's a 0-1 scale :p

Comment: Oh damn! Results still look the same, oh well :/

Comment: I'm gonna say this is just another case of crappy caustics in cycles (fixed soon?).  I have a number of posts on glass, here's a post with a bunch of info and testing, and a potential solution for you at the bottom - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219303/glass-casting-shadows-and-not-looking-real/219957#219957

Comment: [Refraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refraction) is the bending of light rays when passing through a surface between one transparent material and another. In your case - it is a [plate of glass](https://imgur.com/WUK5rbe) ... What do you expect to see in your render?

Comment: @vklidu, I expect to see the lit area to be smaller, however on the contrary, the result is having a larger area.

Comment: Oh sorry for my blindness ... Try to use LuxRender as engine, it is also physically based but from what I spotted it could work better for this specific thing. You are right with Roughness zero the diffuser effect is weird.