# how to create magnified effect on glass

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shader-nodes, effects

hello im new to blender and currently im working on a project of mine its about creating a phone model with transparent plastic case and render it in bledner my question is , is there a way to create a magnified effect on a glass (cycles rendering engine)[image]

to be precise i want the reflection of purple marked place to be longer or at least reflect more (i mean i want that place a bit noisy with reflection ) and red part i want some sort of magnifiying effect like it is noisy with blue color and phone edges are not visible and a bit faded
i know my question is complicated but its something about Refraction of light and i dont know what to do
here is my node setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magnification happens if your glass is shaped to refract the light in that way.

[image]

I suspect what is annoying you is the loss of cast rays due to the ray hitting its bounce limit.

[image]

Effect is a little harder to see here because I'm using the default grey background, but turning up *Total* and *Glossy* bounces will increase the chance that the ray escapes the inside of the glass and finds a light source.

[More Info](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219957/110840)