# How can I make this glass more realistic?

Tags: rendering, texturing, physics, fluid-simulation, glass

I am trying to do a liquid simulation where the fluid is pouring into the glass but I'm not able to make the glass look realistic... Below are some examples:

[image: In-App View]
[image: Render]
[image: Wireframe Render]

Edit: Here is the .blend file

[image]

Comment: Hello maybe try a mix between Glass, Transparent and Glossy nodes? Also the Layer Weight can be used as a Factor

Comment: Glass needs an environment to reflect.  Check all of your normal directions, because it looks like that front face could be flipped.

Comment: @moonboots so I guess just use two mix shaders and connect that way?

Comment: @Allen Simpson What do you mean by normal directions and front face?

Comment: @moonboots that didn't work too well... Have any idea of what I can do? Maybe I should upload the .blend file?

Comment: Maybe be more specific when you say that it's not realistic, in what way is it not? It would be better to have an HDRI image as background so that the glass has something to reflect and see through

Comment: @moonboots see how on the corners it doesn't show the liquid? That's what I'm trying to fix... It's just not rendering well like real glass would if a liquid was being poured into it...

Comment: your file is so small, but the bake time is so big

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing something reasonably complicated here, and it seems like this is one of your first projects.  So this might be a weird and meandering answer...

Glass is weird.  There have been multiple times I have had to sanity check myself, and it's always turned out that I had just never spent that much time looking at that particular thickness of glass, or something.

Here's a picture from real life where I just couldn't believe what I was seeing in blender (a highlight reflection from both the outside and the inside of the glass), and it's the second time that such a realization made me take a picture of the light interaction so as never to forget it...

[image]

although I do seem to have lost that first photo...

What I'm trying to say with all of this is that... You made a geometrically perfect glass object and you set the camera at an exact 45 degree angle, also the background is a gray void so glass objects just look a little strange anyway.  You've never seen that in real life, but I would say it's totally probable that if you did, it would actually act as you see there.

Looking at your glass, it's a thicc boi and it has an inner structure that doesn't match up with the outside.

[image]

That's not your average glass, and so it's not going to have a familiar appearance.

If we add a bevel to match the inner structure up with the outer, I think you'll find the appearance much closer.

[image]

[image]

(By the way I replaced your material with just a *Principled BSDF*.)

And so hopefully that's illustrative of what I was trying to say earlier, but actually we could delete all of the inner structure and use a *Solidify Modifier* and that makes it much easier to adjust the thickness and get the appearance you want.

[image]

[image]

I didn't rebake the simulation here, so the glass is not full, but I think you get the picture.  The appearance of glass is difficult, sometimes especially in this engine, and in blender it's a combination of a lot of things.

Comment: If you're really interested in glass, I have several posts on the topic, but the most comprehensive is probably this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219957/110840

Comment: It isn't my first project, but it is my first liquid simulation... I've build a few houses and done simple animations... I think this might help though, I will comment on your answer if I need any tips :)