# Glass casting opaque shadow in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, shadows, glass

So I've created this glass material  with a color map to get some colored windows, but the light doesnt pass through it. I'm doing it on cycles so i've read a couple of people with similar issues but I do have transparent shadows enabled on my material and the glass bits are basically a plane with subsivisions, so light cant really get trapped inside neither if im correct.
This is my glass material:
[image]

[image]

[image]

and this is my light:
[image]

as you see transparency seems to work fine;
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/219957/110840

Comment: Would recommend the shadow ray workaround for this scene

Comment: @AllenSimpson This worked perfectly thank you!

Comment: If this is _Cycles_ rendering and not _Eevee_, the _Settings_ in the second screenshot are completely irrelevant, the _Alpha Hashed_ Blend/Shadow modes are used by _Eevee_...

Comment: OHH okey thank you!! Still new to rendering in blender